# What are the odds of getting a question answered after offering a 50 point bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I've 100 hard earned reputation points on Stack Overflow.
Last three questions I've asked didn't get any answers.

Now I'm curious, if I offer 50 points as bounty, how will it turn around?

You may want to take a look at my question that I want to offer a bounty on.
[Question is here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743496/how-can-i-add-event-listener-to-google-sheets-link-in-chrome-extensions-content)

Comment: 43.28% ..... :-)   But seriously, we can't predict the future, so any answers we give you will be guesses ... and probably of little value.   (But 43.28% is correct.  Trust me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that is certain is that your question will get more traffic.

That means that more people will look at it. Depending on the clarity, interesting-ness and answerable-ness of your question, votes, up or down, will be cast.

And, if an actual experts read the question, can answer it and wish to do so, you might get an answer.

So we don't know how it will turn around, the only certainty is that there will be more traffic on that question, for better or worse, depending on the quality of that question.